# Moving results from parallel calculation to a final array in Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

I have a parallelized python code that calculates the value of `x[(1,i)]` for `o[(i)]` with i in range `(0, npt)`. As `x[(1,i)] = x1[(i)] * x2[(i)]`, I calculate `x1[(i)]` and `x2[(i)]` separately and then multiply them together to get `x[(1,i)]`.

```py
import cmath, csv, sys, math, re
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp

x1 = np.zeros(npt ,dtype=float)
x2 = np.zeros(npt ,dtype=float)

def chi2(i):
    print("\t wavelength", i+1," of ", npt)
    x1[(i)] = (some function of o[(i)]))

    for k in range(nk):
        for n in range(nb):
            for m in range(nb):
                for l in range(nb):
                        x2[(i)] = (x2[(i)] + (another function of o[(i)]))
    print(i,"x1:",x1[(i)])
    print(i,"x2:",x2[(i)])

    np.set_printoptions(precision=3)
    x[(1,i)] = x1[(i)] * x2[(i)]
    print(i,"x:",x[(1,i)])

    return x[(1,i)]

#-----------single process--------------
for i in range (npt):
    chi2(i)

#------------parallel processes-------------
#pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
#pool.map(chi2,[i for i in range (npt)])
#pool.close() 
#-------------------------------------------

print("x:",x)
```

The output of the "parallel processes" code is as follows:

```
wavelength 1  of  6
wavelength 2  of  6
wavelength 3  of  6
wavelength 4  of  6
wavelength 6  of  6
wavelength 5  of  6
1 x1: 13.064431907056434
1 x2: -1.9906250877567282
1 x: -26.006385911476013
5 x1: 32.428696460232054
5 x2: -7.62814423558251
5 x: -247.37077397057408
2 x1: 16.848860458915905
2 x2: -2.8743277048490476
2 x: -48.429146412197625
3 x1: 21.301496841785333
0 x1: 9.893885346287407
3 x2: -4.053590423587782
0 x2: -1.339636506591729
3 x: -86.34754360594641
0 x: -13.254210001919562
4 x1: 26.47666689558421
4 x2: -5.606053928481043
4 x: -148.42962246307385
x: [[1030. 1130. 1230. 1330. 1430. 1530.]
 [   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]]
```

The parallelized code is able to obtain individual values of `x1[(i)]`, `x1[(i)]`, and `x[(1,i)]`, but is unable to put these values into the full array `print("x:",x)`.

Hence I tried using a single process, and the results are what I wanted:

```
         wavelength 1  of  6
0 x1: 9.893885346287407
0 x2: -1.339636506591729
0 x: -13.254210001919562
         wavelength 2  of  6
1 x1: 13.064431907056434
1 x2: -1.9906250877567282
1 x: -26.006385911476013
         wavelength 3  of  6
2 x1: 16.848860458915905
2 x2: -2.8743277048490476
2 x: -48.429146412197625
         wavelength 4  of  6
3 x1: 21.301496841785333
3 x2: -4.053590423587782
3 x: -86.34754360594641
         wavelength 5  of  6
4 x1: 26.47666689558421
4 x2: -5.606053928481043
4 x: -148.42962246307385
         wavelength 6  of  6
5 x1: 32.428696460232054
5 x2: -7.62814423558251
5 x: -247.37077397057408
x: [[1030.    1130.    1230.    1330.    1430.    1530.   ]
 [ -13.254  -26.006  -48.429  -86.348 -148.43  -247.371]]
```

Can anyone tell me what is preventing the parallelized code from getting values into `x[(1,i)]`?

Comment: When running with multiprocessing, global variables aren't shared between processes that way. Each process will have its own copy of the variable. That being said, you can use the return value of pool.map to get what you want

Comment: @Tomer do you mind writing an example for this? I'm not exactly sure how to use the return value of pool map as you described. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running with multiprocessing, global variables aren't shared between processes that way. Each process will have its own copy of the variable.

Pool.map returns a list of the return values of each function for the list of the given inputs. You could do something like (instead of the pool.map line you use):

```py
x[1] = pool.map(chi2,[i for i in range (npt)])
```

To use the return value of chi2 and insert it in the correct place in x. Note this uses the fact that you can assign a list of values into a column or row of a numpy array.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Originally I was worried that as the sequence of mp output is not in order, directing the results directly to x[1] will lead to wrongly placed values. Your last line helps clarify that. Many thanks!